# PL/SQL Developer doesn't show "ő" character

Tags: windows, oracle, plsql, localization

My problem is that my PL/SQL developer **doesn't show "ő" characters. Instead it shoes "o".**

First I thought that there is problem with the **localization**, but the system locale, and the location is good too(It is set to Hungary).

The Database supports ő characters my team mates can see the characters. I copied their configuration to my PL/SQL developer, still I can't see the "ő" character.

I checked at *Tools->Preferences->Options* that **"Unicode enabled" is checked**.

What can be the problem? I am still thinking that some setting is bad in windows.

Comment: Did you try to change your NLS_LANG in regedit??

Comment: Are you using the same fonts as your co-workers?

Comment: Yes we have the same fonts in PL/SQL developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to change your `NLS_LANG` in your `regedit` to `HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY.EE8MSWIN1250` or somthing like that.

Comment: I changed it now it is HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY.EE8MSWIN1250.

Comment: Thank you!
The problem was that, if I install an Oracle Instant Client, the NLS_LANG need to be changed manually.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PLSQL Developer with instant client - you must set the NLS_LANG manually.